# What is the best way to keep key,value pair in java collection apart from Hashmap?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, hashmap, set

Since hashing is required where value needs to be retrieved from a large set of data. But sometimes this is also possible that we need such collection that can store key, value pair for minimal data.

Comment: LinkedHashMap, TreeMap

Answer (score 2):

Just take a look at the interface `Map` in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html). There you can find other implementations of key-value stores:

> All Known Implementing Classes:
>   AbstractMap, Attributes, AuthProvider, ConcurrentHashMap, ConcurrentSkipListMap, EnumMap, HashMap, Hashtable, Headers, IdentityHashMap, LinkedHashMap, PrinterStateReasons, Properties, Provider, RenderingHints, ScriptObjectMirror, SimpleBindings, TabularDataSupport, TreeMap, UIDefaults, WeakHashMap

Comment: I found a better way of this by storing it in Pair(import javafx.util.Pair;) under JAVA 8. All suggested by you, were used where we need search by key on large storage. Since I was not having need to search after storing in a key value pair.

Comment: @avaneeshkumarShukla I wouldn't say it's better, since you need to add javafx to your application. Not all applications use javafx and including it solely for this reason is an overkill. There is a `Pair` in commons, but it still needs third party dep: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html

Comment: Thanks @Andronicus for better explanation.

Comment: @avaneeshkumarShukla no problem. You can upvote / mark the answer as correct